# Ember.js controller "init" method for authentication

Tags: ember.js

I need to have a controller which I am going to use as the parent of all my other controllers. I need to be able to check the login state, and I don't want to do that by manually calling a method -- I was thinking there must be some kind of method of the parent controller, that might be called automatically.

But I can't find any. Any ideas on this?

Comment: I don't think there's any method built-in that does that for you. I'd recommend you to create a base controller (app level) which your controllers will extend, and you implement this functionality at the base controller. Also keep in mind that with Ember you have more than one controller type option, so you might have to create more than one base type.

Comment: This is what I ended up with. The multiple controller type notice is a great one, thanks!